# Jquery UI Autocomplete up key clears html in my div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete on a content editable div. Using @ as a trigger. The problem is that even though I set the focus event to return false:

```
  focus: function () {
     return false;
  },
```

When using the up and down arrows. If i'm on the first item and hit the up key. Or if i'm on the last result and use the down key. jquery ui autocomplete is clearing all the html elements inside the div.

Can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/YGP8a/

Any idea why or if there's anything I can do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press up or down out of the menu an internal function is called that replaces whatever you have in your div with `request.term` and thus erasing your inputs because, as you can see in the `console.log(term)` of your fiddle, `response.term` has just the text (ignoring your styled inputs).

So after a look in jquery-ui autocomplete source code, just as you rewrite `_rederItem` function, I rewrote `_move` function and it seems to work.

Here's your fiddle edited http://jsfiddle.net/YGP8a/1/.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness, this is what you have to add:

```
$("#testDiv").data("autocomplete")._move = function( direction, event ) {
    if ( !this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
        this.search( null, event );
        return;
    }
    if ( this.menu.isFirstItem() && /^previous/.test( direction ) ||
            this.menu.isLastItem() && /^next/.test( direction ) ) {
            //this._value( this.term ); <-- Here it is!
        this.menu.blur();
        return;
    }
    this.menu[ direction ]( event );
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you, Nefreo! Worked perfectly.

Comment: If you open the dialog and press the escape key, that also clears all of the elements inside the text box...

Comment: @Zhe Thats because upon instantiation of the widget jQuery binds some events with default implementations. To solve this problem you have to redefine the `keydown` event of the widget (thats an awful lot of code). You can see it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/YGP8a/2/). I don't know if I should update the answer with this info, though.

Comment: Thanks so much, Nefreo. I hadn't even noticed the escape key!